# C++ Is conversion from int to long a promotion?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, integer, long-integer

After numerous research on the web, I couldn't figure out if a conversion from int to long is considered as a promotion or not.

If found the following code on the Microsoft's website [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/standard-conversions?view=msvc-160) :

```
long  long_num1, long_num2;
int   int_num;

// int_num promoted to type long prior to assignment.
long_num1 = int_num;
```

However it's not indicated on the [cppreference website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion).

I understand promotion is a conversion that is value-keeping (doesn't change the value when converting).

Could someone help me figure this out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's better to include text as text, instead of images of text.

Comment: It's not a promotion, none of [conv.prom] (see [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.prom)) applies. It it a conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> long  long_num1, long_num2;
> int   int_num;
>
> // int_num promoted to type long prior to assignment.
> long_num1 = int_num;
> ```

The text is incorrect. `int_num` is not *promoted*, because it's already an `int`, so no point applies here.

On [assignment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment), a [*implicit conversion*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_conversions) happens - from source type to destination type. Because `long` can represent all values of `int`, the value is not changed and `int_num` value is converted to a `long` with the same value.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no data loss, as `int` and `long` have both the same size of 4 bytes. You can check whether your compiler agrees with this by running the following code:

```
std::cout << sizeof(int) << ' ' << sizeof(long);
```

The output should be "4 4". That would mean they are both the same.

EDIT: Sorry; thanks for correcting me. The sizes may vary, use a `sizeof` whenever referencing them.

Comment: `int and long have both the same size of 4 bytes` Please don't assume that - it causes novice programmers to incorrectly assume fixed sizes of data types and write hard to fix non-portable code. `int` has __at least__ 16 bits, `long` has __at least__ 32 bits. See [wiki C data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types). See [64-bit data models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) for most common sizes of integers nowadays.

Comment: That's not entirely correct. The only guarantees you get is that a `long` is at least as wide as an `int` (and an `int` being at least 16 bits, incorporated from C). There are platforms where `int` and `long` differ in size.

Comment: @IInspectable -- it's also required that `long` be at least 32 bits.